# Regex for ignoring first and last character

Tags: regex

Trying to obfuscate an email to this format:

```
a***@******m
```

Meaning I need a regex to match everything except first and last character, as well as @.
I can use `[^@]` for everything but how do I ignore the last and first characters in a String? Anchors seem like the way to go but what is the exact syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!^|.$)[^@\s]
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6cOaGU/1)

I also added *white space* to the characters that won't be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

If the tool or language you use supports lookarounds, you can use:

```
(?<!^)[^@](?!$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5Tbaq7/1

Comment: You could replace that negative lookbehind in favor of a negative lookahead so that tools that utilizes JS engine (not ECMA2018) be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language tagged, but if you are using a programming language and you want to make sure that there is an @ sign in the email address and that the first and last character are shown, you might use capturing groups and use replace on the groups that you want to show with an `*`:

```
^(\S)([^@\n]*)(@)([^@\n]*)(\S)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\S)` Capture group 1, match a non whitespace char
- `([^@\s]*)` Capture group 2, match 0+ times not an @ or a whitespace char
- `(@)` Capture group 3, Match `@`
- `([^@\s]*)` Capture group 4, match 0+ times not an @ or a whitespace char
- `(\S)` Capture group 5, match a non whitespace char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wqtjHh/1)

For example using javascript

```js
let pattern = /^(\S)([^@\s]*)(@)([^@\s]*)(\S)$/;
[
  "test@test.com",
  "te st@te st.com",
  "test@test@test.com",
  "te@nl",
  "t@t",
  "test@",
  "@tes",
  "test"
].forEach(str => {
  let replaced = str.replace(pattern, function(_, g1, g2, g3, g4, g5) {
    return g1 + g2.replace(/./g, "*") + g3 + g4.replace(/./g, "*") + g5;
  });
  console.log(replaced);
});
```